# If Statement to determine start and end date

Tags: sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL, and am having a hard time figuring out how to use an if statement I am trying to determine a start date and end date based on today's date. currently, my criteria is set like this:

```
WHERE training.launch_date >= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-04') 
AND training.launch_date <= CONVERT(datetime, '2017-08-10')
```

What I need to do is automate the query , so i need to always have the Start_Date equal the past Friday and the end date be the upcoming Thursday. I was messing with it a little, but cannot seem to figure out the proper syntax. Here is what I have tried, but it isn't working of course.

```
WHERE training.launch_date >= (if(select datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6) 
        Select getdate()
    ELSE (select getdate() - datepart(dw,getdate())))

AND training.launch_date <= (if(select datepart(dw,getdate()) = 6) 
        Select getdate() + 6
    ELSE (select getdate() - datepart(dw,getdate())+6))
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server

Comment: Case statement is what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use flow control statements like `IF` in your queries. You can only use expressions i.e. `CASE WHEN`.

When working with dates you have to remember that "dates" may include time component and therefore it is better to use < next day, rather than expecting an exact date with 00:00:00 hours.

Your query can be written as:

```
SET DATEFIRST 5 

-- Remove hours, minutes etc.
DECLARE @CurrentDay DATETIME = CONVERT( DATE, GETDATE())

SELECT *
.....
WHERE training.launch_date >= @CurrentDay + 1 - DATEPART( dw, @CurrentDay )
    AND training.launch_date < @CurrentDay + 8 - DATEPART( dw, @CurrentDay )
```

Explanation:

`SET DATEFIRST` - sets the first day of the week. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql)

If for some reason you do not want to use `SET DATEFIRST`, then you can manually offset the start of the week:

```
DATEPART( dw, @CurrentDay + 2 )
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
declare @date datetime = '20170815'

SELECT 
    case 
        when datepart(weekday, @date) >5 then
        DATEADD(DAY, 4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) 
        else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, @date), 0)) 
    end
    ,DATEADD(DAY,(CASE DATEPART(DW,@date) 
                    WHEN 5 THEN 7
                    WHEN 6 THEN 6
                    WHEN 7 THEN 5
                    ELSE 5 - DATEPART(DW,@date) END),@date)
```

**So in your code...**

```
WHERE 
    training.launch_date >= case 
                                when datepart(weekday, getdate()) >5 then
                                DATEADD(DAY, 4, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
                                else DATEADD(DAY, -3, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
                            end
    AND training.launch_date <=DATEADD(DAY,(CASE DATEPART(DW,getdate()) 
                                            WHEN 5 THEN 7
                                            WHEN 6 THEN 6
                                            WHEN 7 THEN 5
                                            ELSE 5 - DATEPART(DW,getdate()) END),getdate())
```